# Sorting related accounts by reputation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, linked-accounts

More and more sites are coming into the SE family. As such, when going into the accounts tab of some users, there is sometimes quite a big number of associated accounts. Until now, they are displayed in a <del>random</del> "arbitrary" order, but it could be useful to be able to sort them by reputation, to see in which sites said user is active.

Comment: Oh yes, [do want](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135907/regdwight?tab=accounts).

Comment: @Reg, I was looking your user page when I thought about this feature.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I have returned the favor by looking at yours. (^_^)

Comment: @Reg, do you automatically suscribe to any new site as soon as the public beta is open? Also you seems to have a lot of fanatic badges.

Comment: Well, not really "automatically". As to those Fanatic badges, that's not a script, either. (I have actually visited all those sites, several times a day, looking at the questions and leaving an upvote, a comment, or even an answer or two here and there.)

Comment: @Reg I wasn't implying that a bot was behind it or anything, I was just amazed by your level of activity.

Comment: while we wait for this feature to be implemented, maybe someone wrote a simple greasemonkey script to fix this?

Comment: @UncleZeiv, it doesn't seems like anyone is up to it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The accounts tab has been significantly improved and offers this functionality built in:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135907/regdwight?tab=accounts

Answer (score 7):

The order does not appear to actually be random.  It looks like stack overflow, flowed by server fault, then superuser, and so on.  Not sure the order the sites were released but that could be the order that the accounts are in.

I think sorting by Rep would be a great idea as it would show where a user was most active.  Also it for users like RegDwight, it might be useful to resort the accounts by name or have some way to search to see if they have an account on "site X".

Comment: Oh well, it seems that it isn't sorted at random like it used to be. But my point still stand.

Comment: @eld so why did you accept this answer?

Comment: @Tshepang because it correspond to what I want. As soon as a fix has been done, if there is a new answer with it, I might migrate my accepted answer. And also, the fact that I accepted this answer doesn't mean that there isn't better answers out there. If there is, I just don't know about it.

Comment: @eld Next time I should read a bit more thoroughly. I didn't notice that the guy said __sorting by Rep would be a great idea__.

Comment: By now, the sort order is depending from where I'm looking at that. At least it should be the same sort order on every account.

Comment: @user: Where are the accounts sorted differently?