# Area 51 Associated Accounts Are Arranged Aimlessly

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, profile-page, linked-accounts

...I originally didn't plan to go that far but the "Are" kinda convinced me to.

As mentioned [in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74843/sorting-related-accounts-by-reputation), there was a recent update which has changed it to sort to a specific order which is roughly by launch date.

Thanks to code fork and all that, Area 51 did not get this update, so associated accounts still randomize their order when you load the page. I'm happy because shuffling my flair on refresh is fun in a silly way, but for consistency it should probably be the same behavior as on the other sites.

Comment: Well, obviously +1.

Comment: +1 because I would give +2 (one for the alliteration, another for the question that annoys me too) if I could

Comment: Nice. You even got 5 words to the right of the 51 and 1 word to the left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like the rest of the network, Area 51 now sorts associated accounts by "Site Id", which is roughly equivalent to launch date.