# Drag and drop sort of accounts, and sort by column in Accounts Tab

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, tabs

Similar to [**this question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74843/154443) on sorting by Reputation on the Accounts tab, I would really like to have the following functionality:

- **Sort by column** - to allow sorting by alphabetical name of site or by questions etc in addition to the standard sort by rep
- **Drag and drop sorting** - so I could move my meta stackoverflow account to be next to my stackoverflow one (currently my meta is a lot higher up my list than SO)

(does no-one want this but me?)

Comment: Not sure I understand the need for the drag and drop sorting but the column sorting could be useful I suppose.

Comment: The drag and drop is so I can order my accounts any way I want.