# How SE related accounts are sorted by in user profile

Tags: discussion, profile-page, sorting, linked-accounts

How Stack Exchange related accounts are sorted by in user page.

Sorted by `[rep]`, `[badges]` `[answers]`?

Also i have two other accounts with same `[rep]` my **x** account has more badges than the **y** account and the **x** account is showing after the **y** account, doesn't it matter on sorting if **x** account earned more badges than **y**?

Comment: Answer is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74843/152859 and as for downvotes, people probably thought it's too trivial.

Comment: @ShadowWizard its kinda same but not the answer i was looking for.

Comment: "Sorting related accounts by reputation" then "they are displayed in a random order": that's the answer to what you asked.

Comment: Related: [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190768/sorting-of-accounts-in-profile-summary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190768/182513), however, the new topbar has rendered most of what I was looking for moot.

Comment: I have read through all the above related questions before asking. @ShadowWizard Yes i got my answer!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Why this question isn't duplicated of that instead?

Comment: Because it's asked better with a screenshot.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't think so, this question has been asked before to that question.

Comment: @RahilWazir http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha (Shog9 is highest ranking employee of Stack Exchange)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I agree to that (And I know about shog). But it feels to me that this should not need to be closed. If you are talking about a screen-shot then its not the case. Better in a sense means that it should be easy to understand. And both question and the answer here is understandable

Comment: The other (newer) one is indeed easier to understand. If you want you're free to cast a Reopen vote on your own question, if four other 3K users will agree with you, it will be reopened. I'm just ordinary user with my own opinion, and won't fight it any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are ordered by reputation regardless of the badges you earned. The rest is simply randomized.

Comment: True, it's randomized for the same reason answers with same score are displayed in random order.