# How are accounts sorted in Network Profile if they have the same rep?

Tags: support, user-accounts, sorting, network-profile

How are accounts sorted if they have the same rep?

[image]

I don't see any logic.

Comment: Like other lists (e.g. same score answers) it's just sorted randomly then cached. Couldn't find official post about it regarding the accounts list, but I'm pretty sure that's correct. Good chance you will see different order when the cache is rebuilt, e.g. when you join a new site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How SE related accounts are sorted by in user profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215031/how-se-related-accounts-are-sorted-by-in-user-profile)

Comment: @ShadowWizard http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215031/how-se-related-accounts-are-sorted-by-in-user-profile?rq=1#comment699434_216160 ;)

Comment: Nice find @hichris however this one here is asked better and more clearly, so used my hammer to close the older one as dupe. (back then I just didn't bother to test it, so didn't come with an answer :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard *Totally* not because you have an answer here. ;P (IMO the older one is a good dupe target too, sooo...)

Comment: @hichris123 I would do the same even without having answer here - and the votes on the questions also kind of indicate which is better asked. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, just tested it and pretty sure I found the algorithm. First sort is of course reputation. Then when there is a reputation change in a site that cause same score with other sites, the sort algorithm just push the site with the change randomly between the others.

To test it, I joined https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ and see where it is in [the list](https://stackexchange.com/users/201110/shadow-wizard?tab=accounts):

> [image]

100% random, however the order of all others is kept i.e. only changed rep site will change position.

Comment: Take  note of [this](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1675011#1675011)

Comment: @rene not sure it's the same, she was talking about "top reviewers of the day"

Comment: I know but the comment is universal IMHO

Comment: @rene nope, e.g. we know for sure same score answers are sorted randomly, on purpose, so maybe same reason applies here.

Comment: I wonder how that works with network-wide suspensions ...

Comment: @Glorfindel that's a good question lol. Doubt the suspension is considered "score change", so most likely order is simply kept as-is. Need to ask a CM to put network wide suspension on a sock account to know for sure. ;)