# Order of Communities in user profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, sorting, communities-list

I noticed that the shown communities on the profile of every user are ordered by the reputation the user has in the different community.

> [image: Screenshot Communities order]

But if an user has the same reputation in two communities they seem to be ordered randomly. This is also metioned in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234596/340973).

> [image: Screenshot Communities order with same reputation]]

I would suggest to change this so it is sorted by the overall activity in the specific communities, for example based on posts and/or badges or even based on personal preference.

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree with *activity* being the sorting criterion (I can think of some others), but I do agree that there should be *some* order to it. (In fact, I find it very unlikely that the site generates the order randomly. There is likely some algorithm to it that is just not apparent to the viewer.)

Comment: I don't think it's ordered "randomly" so much as "by when the site was created". Obviously that's not a *useful* ordering, but it is an ordering ;)

Comment: According to this post it is random: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234596/340973

Comment: My inclination would be to sort by the user's "age" in the community - that is, for all communities with reputation _n_, list them in the order the user joined.

Comment: @NicolBolas it's random, I tested it, and the OP of this question is proof it's not using the site age, e.g. Space Exploration is older than IPS.

Comment: It would be great if you could click/press-drag them into whichever order you choose, displaying the top 5 chosen communities on your profile page for all to see and the remainder in the order you prefer for visiting/seeing.

Comment: [Related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291708/339911) for hidden communities.